# Twilio date filter in Python messages.list command no longer working

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to pull a list of messages sent since the last time I did a pull from the Twilio API, and it suddenly stopped working on 2/27. Before, I had been using client.messages.list(date_sent_after=last_run) where last_run is the date of the last pull. Now when I run that command I get an error of " list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_sent_after' "

Since that command stopped working, I've also tried client.messages.list(date_sent>='2024-02-25') which gives me an error of "date_sent is not defined", and I've tried client.messages.list(date_sent='>=2024-02-25' which gives me an error of "invalid date value". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?